# How to create property by condition in spring application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-properties

how can I create an if conditional in the spring applicaiton.properties file?.

for example:

```
restart.enabled=true
project.name=(restart.enabled == true) ? "restartProjectName" : "projectName"
```

thanks for all :)

Comment: Unless you have some additional processing for properties files, I don't think this is possible. Instead, you could define the restart project name and default project name as properties and a bean that selects between them given the `restart.enabled` property.

Comment: thanks but I need it like that, if there is no way to do that I will tack your answer as a reference, thanks :)

Comment: You could try using [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)